# c# making text change colour when checked

Tags: c#

I am trying to make the text of the button change colour when a checkbox is checked, but for some reason, I just don't know how. Would I need to write an If statement, if so how do I do that?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColourCheckBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }

    private void ColourCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColourCheckBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;    
    }
}
```

Comment: What should the `if` be checking?

Comment: What you mean "check button"? Maybe press?

Comment: the code looks right (as far as goes with your question), doesn't the color change?)

Comment: Are you looking for  `ColourCheckBox.Checked` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is so obscure, but based on the things that I understand, you should check the `Checked` property.

```
private void ColourCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ColourCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        ColourCheckBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
    else
    {
        ColourCheckBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [`CheckedChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) event, you can use the [`Checked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked) property:

```
ColourCheckBox.ForeColor = ColourCheckBox.Checked ? Color.Black : Color.Red;
```

In case of a Triple state checkbox, with 3 color you can switch on  [`CheckState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkstate?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_CheckBox_CheckState) value :

1. Unchecked = 0
2. Checked = 1
3. Indeterminate = 2

Answer (score 0):

using System.Drawing;

```js
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
                button1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
```